# Entity Framework Core: ignoring column map when column not present in stored procedure result

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Sometimes the stored procedure does not send `site_city`, `site_state` and `site_zip` based on site. When it doesn't send all the columns as in the model, I get this error:

> The required column 'site_city' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

My code:

```
public class ReportMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Report>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Report> builder)
    {
        builder.HasNoKey();
        builder.Property(v => v.SiteId).HasColumnName("site_id");
        builder.Property(v => v.SiteName).HasColumnName("site_name");
        builder.Property(v => v.SiteAddress).HasColumnName("site_address");
        builder.Property(v => v.SiteCity).HasColumnName("site_city");
        builder.Property(v => v.SiteState).HasColumnName("site_state");
        builder.Property(v => v.SiteZip).HasColumnName("site_zip");
    }
}

public class Report
{
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string SiteAddress { get; set; }
        public string SiteCity { get; set; }
        public string SiteState { get; set; }
        public string SiteZip { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make the model work for both scenarios? So when column is not present in result of stored procedure, then it should not map that column.

Comment: Simplest way is to modify your stored procedure to sent those columns with null or defautl values. The EF model is constructed before even connectin to the database so you can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without touching the stored procedure? So when column not present then it shouldn't map to the column and just have null in the column value?

Comment: Not by using ORM like EF Core but you can by using ADO.Net

Comment: The official EF Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations) explicitly states: *"The SQL query **must** return data for **all** properties of the entity type*"